# Интересны результат запроса GET в терминале Ubuntu к VK

Tags: get

Пишу в терминале такой запрос:

```
 GET http 1.1 Host vk.com
```

По логике, я должен получить `html` код который можно увидеть перейдя как не зарегистрированный пользователь ([адрес](http://vk.com) на тот случай, если кто не знает). Но результат не такой, а с информацией о **hosting@*****.net**. Откуда и почему эта информация в ответе?

*P.S. Скрыл название, чтобы не рекламировать.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что вы указываете НЕ хост vk.com, а HTTP-заголовок, [который импользуется для виртуального хостинга](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38419498/why-does-the-host-address-is-included-in-http-1-1-get-command).

Что бы получить html страницу Контакта нужно просто вызвать

```
GET vk.com
```

Вы так же можете сравнить заголовки запросов,  например так

```
GET vk.com -U > test1.html 

GET http 1.1 Host vk.com > test2.html
```

и результаты что то типа
`GET http://http User-Agent: lwp-request/6.31 libwww-perl/6.31` и `GET http://www.vk.com/ User-Agent: lwp-request/6.31 libwww-perl/6.31` соответственно